# Issue with binding and DBNull. Exception raised only once

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I have a datatable with two columns C1 & C2. **(C1 has AllowDBNull = false)**. The datatable is created as follows :

```
Private Function GetDataTable() As DataTable
    Dim DT As New DataTable

    'Create the first column
    Dim C As New DataColumn("C1")
    C.AllowDBNull = False
    DT.Columns.Add(C)

    'Second column
    DT.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("C2"))

    Return DT
End Function
```

Then I have a form with two text boxes bound to the datatable :

```
Dim DT As DataTable = GetDataTable()
Dim CurrencyManager As CurrencyManager = CType(Me.BindingContext(DT), CurrencyManager)

'Add the bindings
TextBox1.BindingContext = Me.BindingContext
TextBox2.BindingContext = Me.BindingContext

TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", DT, "C1", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation))
TextBox2.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", DT, "C2", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation))

'Set the null value of the Textbox1
TextBox1.DataBindings(0).NullValue = ""
```

I'm setting the NullValue of the textBox1 such that whenever the textbox is "", it should be considered as DBNull.

I insert a new row using the CurrencyManager :

```
'Insert a new row
CurrencyManager.AddNew()

'Fill the two columns...
Dim Row As DataRowView = CurrencyManager.Current
Row.Row.Item(0) = "Column 1 Value"
Row.Row.Item(1) = "Column 2 Value"

'Validate the entry
CurrencyManager.EndCurrentEdit()  'No issue here since
```

Now when the user clears the FirstTextBox (which datatable column has AllowDBNull false) if I run the following code twice. The **first time an exception is raised** and the msgbox is displayed, however **the second time it doesn't raise an exception** and it takes back the previous value which is "Column 1 Value" and the column is not anymore dbnull.

```
Try
    CurrencyManager.EndCurrentEdit()
Catch ex As Exception
    msgbox("The field C1 can not be empty")
End Try
```

My question is : is there any way to make the last code always raise an exception when the field is empy ?

Cheers,

Comment: I find your naming conventions confusing. `Dim CurrencyManager As CurrencyManager` is it the data type or an instance variable? `Dim Row As DataRowView = CurrencyManager.Current
Row.Row.Item(0)` just looks strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that I am understanding your goal correctly, then something like this should work.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    Try
        CurrencyManager.EndCurrentEdit()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("The field C1 can not be empty")
        TextBox1.DataBindings(0).WriteValue() ' push the value to the datasource
        e.Cancel = True
    End Try
End Sub
```

Edit:  I just want to state that this use of an exception for validation is not recommended as you could easily validate the text without using an exception.  This also assumes that this could is placed in the validating event; an assumption on my part that my be incorrect.